# Python return in _init_ constructor

Tags: python, constructor, init

```
class Adder:

    result = 0

    def __init__( self, number1, number2 ):
        self.result = int( number1 ) + int( number2 )

    def giveResult( self ):
        return str(self.result)

class AdderGui:

    def __init__( self ):
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("Adder.glade")

    def add(self, widget):
        entry1 = self.builder.get_object ("entry1")
        entry2 = self.builder.get_object ("entry2")
        try:
            thistime = adder( entry1.get_text(), entry2.get_text() )
        except ValueError:
            self.builder.get_object("hboxWarning").show()
            self.builder.get_object("entryResult").set_text("ERROR")
            return 0

    def quit(self, widget):
        sys.exit(0)
```

what i don't understand here how does thistime variable gets the value of addition. Since *init* always return none it should not get the value of addition.

Comment: It's worth noting that methods designed only to access variables (``giveResult()``) are bad practice in Python. Look up the ``property`` decorator/builtin.

Comment: It is even more worth noting, that in Python 2.x you should always inherit you classes from "object", or be subject to subtle errors. 
(You are inheriting from nothing, which makes them old style classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. `thistime` is assigned an `Adder` object. To get the result, you'll need to call its `giveResult()` method. For example:

```
result = thistime.giveResult()
```

By the way, class names should by convention be capitalized. Also, `result = 0` doesn't seem to make much sense in the `Adder` class definition. Object variable `self.result` is assigned in `__init__()`.